# Python script for Network Packet Capture in Nifi

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I am new to the nifi platform.

I am trying to use a python script to capture network packet which works on VScode and want to implement same script using NiFi but unable to do so.

This python code I used:

```
import os, subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
from datetime import datetime

n = 10
filename = str(datetime.now()).replace(" ","")
b = subprocess.run(f'sudo tcpdump udp -e -i wlp6s0 -nn -vvv -c {n} -w {filename}.raw',shell=True)

c = '"X%02x"'
a = subprocess.run(f"sudo hexdump -v -e '1/1 {c}' {filename}.raw| sed -e 's/\s\+//g' -e 's/X/\\x/g' ", shell=True , stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

output_file = open (f'{filename}.txt', 'w')
output_file.write(str(a.stdout))
# print("*************************File Created*************************")

output_file.close()
```

I am using Execute Script Processor for implementing the python script. But it doesn't seem to be working. For executing the "sudo command" I have set to use no password so that no input is needed while executing the script.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just calling shell commands, you might consider ExecuteStreamCommand instead. You can still run the top-level Python script to call the subprocesses, but since you're not working with flowfile attributes you might be better served being able to call "real" Python. In ExecuteScript the engine is actually Jython and it doesn't let you import native (CPython) modules such as `scikit`, you can only import pure Python modules (Python scripts that don't themselves import native modules)

Comment: Thank you @mattyb for replying my question. Subprocess is also one of the native modules of python. As much as I can understand ExecuteScript should run the mentioned script. Could you suggest any changes in the script which can help in running the script without changing the output?

Comment: It looks like Jython has its own `subprocess` module (https://www.jython.org/jython-old-sites/docs/library/subprocess.html) that doesn't appear to have some of the same methods (like `run`) that the Python one does. The link I sent does mention you can use `call` to run programs, not sure if that helps or not.